Creating temporal raster (timeseries) in PyQGIS
QGIS can animate a temporal raster using the Temporal Controller. I am trying to programmatically create a layer in Python that can be animated in this way.
What I can do so far is to create a numpy array and set it as the layer content. Something like
from scipy_filters.helpers import RasterWizard

wizard = RasterWizard()
myarray = np.ones((3,100,100)) # 3 bands, 100x100 pixels
layer = wizard.tolayer(myarray , name='ones') #in memory layer

However, I don't know how to make this layer "playable" through the Temporal Controler. For example, how and where do I set the timestamps for every frame? How do I mark the layer to contain a temporal raster?
Alternatively, I can use the Time Manager plugin to play. However, in that case, I would need to set the gdal TIMESERIES metadata on the layer's source and I don't know how to do that either.

For a raster layer to be controlled by the temporal controller it needs to have some active temporal properties set. The most basic of these options is setting a fixed time range for the layer as shown in the screenshot below:

This can be set using PyQGIS as follows:
rl = iface.activeLayer()

# Set up the layer's QgsRasterLayerTemporalProperties
t_props = rl.temporalProperties()
t_props.setMode(Qgis.RasterTemporalMode.FixedTemporalRange)
t_props.setFixedTemporalRange(QgsDateTimeRange(QDateTime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0), QDateTime(2023, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)))
t_props.setIsActive(True)

This option is not really useful for a single layer on its own, but in this way you can create a time series by setting fixed ranges for multiple raster layers which can then be animated in sequence.
Since QGIS 3.38, a couple of other options for temporal settings have been added. These are: Fixed Time Range Per Band and Represents Temporal Values:


Below are a couple of complete examples which you can paste into a blank editor and run in the Python console (QGIS version >= 3.38) which show the complete process of creating random raster layers, applying a renderer, setting the temporal properties and animating them with the temporal controller.
Firstly using Fixed Time Range Per Band with a 4-band raster:
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
project = QgsProject.instance()

random_rasters = []
b_min = 1000
b_max = 2000

for i in range(4):
    rr_params = {'EXTENT':'-235000.000000000,-110000.000000000,10581150.000000000,10679150.000000000 [EPSG:32735]',
            'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32735'),
            'PIXEL_SIZE':500,
            'OUTPUT_TYPE':5,
            'LOWER_BOUND':b_min,
            'UPPER_BOUND':b_max,
            'CREATE_OPTIONS':None,
            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
    random_rasters.append(processing.run("native:createrandomuniformrasterlayer", rr_params)['OUTPUT'])
    #processing.runAndLoadResults("native:createrandomuniformrasterlayer", rr_params)
    b_min+=1000
    b_max+=1000

vrt_params = {'INPUT':random_rasters,
            'RESOLUTION':0,
            'SEPARATE':True,
            'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':False,
            'ADD_ALPHA':False,
            'ASSIGN_CRS':None,
            'RESAMPLING':0,
            'SRC_NODATA':'',
            'EXTRA':'',
            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:buildvirtualraster", vrt_params)

# Start with multi-band QgsRasterLayer object
rl = project.mapLayersByName('Virtual')[0]

# Get min & max values of raster stack
band_mins = []
band_maxes = []

prov = rl.dataProvider()
band_count = prov.bandCount()

for i in range(band_count):
    b_stats = prov.bandStatistics(i+1)
    band_mins.append(b_stats.minimumValue)
    band_maxes.append(b_stats.maximumValue)

rmin = min(band_mins)
rmax = max(band_maxes)

# Use single band pseudocolor renderer with classification set to min & max of raster stack
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(prov, 1)
style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
color_ramp = style.colorRamp('Viridis')
renderer.setClassificationMin(rmin)
renderer.setClassificationMax(rmax)
renderer.createShader(color_ramp)
rl.setRenderer(renderer)
rl.triggerRepaint()

# Create sequential time ranges of 23hrs & 59mins for each band
band_range_map = {}

start_dt = QDateTime(2024, 10, 20, 0, 0)
for i in range(band_count):
    end_dt = start_dt.addDays(1).addSecs(-60)
    dt_range = QgsDateTimeRange(start_dt, end_dt)
    band_range_map[i+1] = dt_range
    start_dt = start_dt.addDays(1)

# Create the time range for the animation
t_ext = QgsDateTimeRange(band_range_map[1].begin().addDays(-1), band_range_map[band_count].end().addDays(-1))

# Set up the layer's QgsRasterLayerTemporalProperties
t_props = rl.temporalProperties()
t_props.setMode(Qgis.RasterTemporalMode.FixedRangePerBand)
t_props.setFixedRangePerBand(band_range_map)
t_props.setIsActive(True)

# Set up the QgsTemporalNavigationObject
tc = canvas.temporalController()
tc.setNavigationMode(QgsTemporalNavigationObject.Animated)
tc.setTemporalExtents(t_ext)
interval = QgsInterval()
interval.setDays(1.0)
tc.setFrameDuration(interval)
tc.setFramesPerSecond(1.0)
tc.rewindToStart()
tc.setLooping(True)
# Optionally open the Temporal Controller (not required)
tca = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionTemporalController')
if not tca.isChecked():
    tca.trigger()
###
tc.playForward()

Result:

And using pixels to represent temporal values (here pixel values are 1-12 representing time offset in months from a starting date):
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
project = QgsProject.instance()

rr_params = {'EXTENT':'-235000.000000000,-110000.000000000,10581150.000000000,10679150.000000000 [EPSG:32735]',
        'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32735'),
        'PIXEL_SIZE':500,
        'OUTPUT_TYPE':1,
        'LOWER_BOUND':1,
        'UPPER_BOUND':12,
        'CREATE_OPTIONS':None,
        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:createrandomuniformrasterlayer", rr_params)

rl = project.mapLayersByName('Output raster')[0]

prov = rl.dataProvider()

renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(prov, 1)
style = QgsStyle.defaultStyle()
color_ramp = style.colorRamp('Viridis')
renderer.setClassificationMin(1)
renderer.setClassificationMax(12)
renderer.createShader(color_ramp)
rl.setRenderer(renderer)
rl.triggerRepaint()

# Set up the layer's QgsRasterLayerTemporalProperties
t_props = rl.temporalProperties()
t_props.setMode(Qgis.RasterTemporalMode.RepresentsTemporalValues)
t_props.setTemporalRepresentationOffset(QDateTime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0))
t_props.setTemporalRepresentationScale(QgsInterval(1.0, Qgis.TemporalUnit.Months))
t_props.setIsActive(True)

t_ext = QgsDateTimeRange(QDateTime(2023, 1, 15, 23, 59, 59), QDateTime(2023, 12, 15, 23, 59, 59))

# Set up the QgsTemporalNavigationObject
tc = canvas.temporalController()
tc.setNavigationMode(QgsTemporalNavigationObject.Animated)
tc.setTemporalExtents(t_ext)
interval = QgsInterval()
interval.setMonths(1.0)
tc.setFrameDuration(interval)
tc.setFramesPerSecond(1.0)
tc.rewindToStart()
tc.setLooping(True)
# Optionally open the Temporal Controller (not required)
tca = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, 'mActionTemporalController')
if not tca.isChecked():
    tca.trigger()
###
tc.playForward()

Result:

Here is a link to a YouTube video from Hans van der Kwast on animating multi-band rasters:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL8kpqdiReg

Hi Ben, thank you so much for this detailed answer! This is great and worked like a charm after I upgraded to the latest QGIS version (I still had the long term version which is currently 3.34)

@Christoph, that's great- no problem.
